# toLowerCase() clones previous input symbols (only on device not in the simulator)

Tags: android, react-native, redux-form, normalize

I wanted to implement a normalizer for a username Field (I use Redux form), which would result in all of the capital letters being immediately transformed to lowercase.

I used the [Redux Form normalizing example](https://redux-form.com/6.0.1/examples/normalizing/), and it worked very well on the Android Emulator (exactly as in the link above, so I didn't record it).

However, I decided to test it on an Android device (Samsung Galaxy S8+ with Android 8.0) and ran into a weird case: the first letter got lowercased perfectly, but inputting any other letters [would clone the previously input ones.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8dM1.jpg). The same happened when I ran the app on my coworker's Xperia with Android 6.0.

Finally, after failing to figure it out, I just moved the normalization to my login saga, where I just split the body into *username: action.loginForm.username.toLowerCase(), password:(...)*. However, I'm curious if any of you have encountered a similar bug/know how to solve it? Such knowledge would definitely make the code more readable:)

Comment: Have same bug on S8+. Do you think it is a device issue?

Comment: @ProllyGeek sorry, I forgot to mention: I ran it also on Android 6 (Huawei), so it's neither Samsung's, not Android v. 8's issue.

Comment: is same issue happening on Huawei, or not? For me on Nexus, and Huawei it was working fine (simulator as well), only S8+ had that issue.

Comment: @ProllyGeek it was an Xperia M5.

Comment: The gif link you have posted appears to be broken. Could you post the code you have used, or upload it to snack.expo.io?

Comment: @jevakallio updated the link to imgur, also cut out the most important parts to https://pastebin.com/WZTEVzK0